# Centered flexible div with elastic adjacent divs

Tags: html, css

I need a flexible div width in between two flexible width divs, like so :

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the tricky part: my middle part needs to react like this:

```
#middle {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 96em;       /* +/- 960px */
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

However, `#left` and `#right` need to be visible and take the remaining space, like the picture below shows:

[image]

As a reference, my header and footer will be the same width of `#middle`.

### (NOT) Failed attempt {0}

Calling this like such since I have not (and will not) use a `<table>` structure for obvious reasons. (Though `Failed attempt 2` was a CSS equivalent for the same logic.)

### Failed attempt 1

```
#main { position: relative; }
#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 35%; /* arbitrary width for dev. purposes */
    width: calc(35% - 30px); /* arbitrary width for dev. purposes */
}
#middle {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 96rem;
    margin: 0 auto
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 35%; /* arbitrary width for dev. purposes */
    width: calc(35% - 30px); /* arbitrary width for dev. purposes */
}
```

**problem:** Did not keep a constant spacing between `#middle` and `#left`/`#right` on window resize (quick substitute for multiple device widths)

### Failed attempt 2

```
#main { display: table-row; /* also tried display: table; */ }
#left, #right, #middle { display: table-cell; }
```

**problem:** Did not allow for `#middle` to be centered at 90% width width max-width

Comment: If you want a _pure_ CSS solution, you can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: its 2013, i would go javascript with a fixed width fallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `calc()` and `float`. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmu8J/4/).

If you change your html to this, with the middle div coming last:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

... then change your css to this:

```
#main {  
height:100%;
background:aqua;
}

#left {
float:left;
background:black;
height:100%;
width:9%;
width: -webkit-calc(10% - 30px);
width: -moz-calc(10% - 30px);
width: calc(10% - 30px);
}

#right {
float:right;
background:black;
height:100%;
width:9%;
width: -webkit-calc(10% - 30px);
width: -moz-calc(10% - 30px);
width: calc(10% - 30px);
}

#middle {
width: calc(90% - 60px);
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background:white;
height:100%;
}
```

To accommodate the max width, since it changes the percentage calculation, I figured out the breakpoint (the point at which the browser started using the `max-width`) and changed the width of the sidebars with a `@media` query:

```
@media all and (min-width : 1134px) {

#left, #right{
    width: -webkit-calc(((100% - 960px) / 2) - 30px);
    width: -moz-calc(((100% - 960px) / 2) - 30px);
    width: calc(((100% - 960px) / 2) - 30px);
}
}
```

There is still a tiny bit of variability in the width of the padding, since it is calculated using percentages. I did the `calc()` math kind of quick so there may be a better way to do the calculation, but all in all, it works. And no tables.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! I had to play with a few media queries but all and out the basics of it is there. Since we are dealing with floats, I suggest adding this to keep all heights equal: `$(document).ready(function(){var height = Math.max($("#left").height(),$("#right").height(),$("#middle").height());$("#left").height(height);$("#right").height(height);$("#middle").height(height)});` Thanks !